# What are some good resources on analytic aesthetics?

Tags: analytic-philosophy, continental-philosophy, aesthetics

Always I see resources about view of continental-philosophy about aesthetics, is there any resource about view of analytic-philosophy about aesthetics? which philosopher of analytic-philosophy talks about aesthetics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start there's a great SEP entry on Wittgentein's aesthetics claiming some felicity between Wittgenstein's analytic preoccupation and his aesthetics:

> **...and in many more cases suggests implicitly, the layered interconnections between aesthetic considerations and every other area of philosophy upon which he wrote.**

As most already know, one of Wittgenstein's famous  engrossments within the analytic tradition is that of stamping out inconsistencies in language, and herein it is suggested that aesthetic language is suspect to similar scrutiny.

There's also a treatment of **depiction** and **narrative** from an epistemic/philosophy-of-mind point of view. Some papers to read include [Pictorial Diversity](http://fds.oup.com/www.oup.com/pdf/13/9780199585960_chapter1.pdf), [Pictorial Resemblance](http://kar.kent.ac.uk/31634/1/Newall,%20%27Pictorial%20Resemblance%27.pdf), and Defining Depiction (which I could not find for free).
Hope this helped.